# Curve with acnodes over closed fields?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

From Wikipedia:

> An **acnode** is an isolated point not on a curve, but whose coordinates satisfy the equation of the curve. The term "isolated point" or "hermit point" is an equivalent term.

I was just wondering... is it possible, for a curve over an algebraically closed field, to present acnodes?

My guess is that they can be encountered only over non closed fields.

Comment: Are you only interested in *affine plane curves*, as Wikipedia seems to suggest?

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in just affine plane curves, then the answer is no, there are no acnodes possible over algebraically closed fields.

If $f(x,y)\in k[x,y]$ had an acnode at the origin for example, then it would have a point as an irreducible component, which is not possible since $f(x,y)=0$ defines a hypersurface which in turn means each irreducible component has dimension 1.

Comment: You might also want to glimpse through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_a_curve#Acnodes    Acnodes are mentioned in addition to other singularities. In particular the difference between the $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ cases are mentioned.

Comment: When working in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ for example, $x^2+y^2=0$ is satisfied only by the origin $(0,0)$, and so here, the origin is defined by a hypersurface. In $k[x,y]$ where $k$ is algebraically closed, it is not possible to define the origin by the vanishing set of a hypersurface.